# How to convert name to pig latin with an sfdc formula?

Tags: formula-field

I'm at Dreamforce and attending a "hack a thon" session. The task is to convert the name of each Contact into Pig Latin only using "clicks", not code.
I thought creating 2 formula fields, 1 for first name and 1 for last name might work but I cant seem to find a way to create the formula and it's driving me crazy.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need 2 formulas unless you want to break it up, you can do it all on one formula.  I can;t just give you the formulas as that would not be right, but I will tell you you should look into leveraging the LEFT() and right RIGHT() functions.  Those are really all you need with a couple of IF()s.  Maybe if you share what you have so far, we can give better help.

Comment: Does the challenge really expect you to have a formula, how many contacts are we talking in this challenge?>

Comment: You do not **have** to use formulas.  It does need to be dynamic though so an update to the name is reflected in the pig latin name so that does certainly limit your options.

Comment: I posted an answer, but just realised this is for something at Dreamforce. I'll undelete my answer once Dreamforce is over (unless there are no prizes involved for completing this).

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry I didn't respond sooner. First, it wasn't a challenge and no prizes awarded. This is what I ended up with:

Comment: IF(ISBLANK(FirstName), "", IF(Upper(LEFT(FirstName,1))="A" || Upper(LEFT(FirstName,1))="E" || Upper(LEFT(FirstName,1))="I" || Upper(LEFT(FirstName,1))="O" || Upper(LEFT(FirstName,1))="U" || Upper(LEFT(FirstName,1))="Y", FirstName&"way", IF(Upper(MID(FirstName,2,1))="A" || Upper(MID(FirstName,2,1))="E" || Upper(MID(FirstName,2,1))="I" || Upper(MID(FirstName,2,1))="O" || Upper(MID(FirstName,2,1))="U" || Upper(MID(FirstName,2,1))="Y", MID(FirstName, 2, (LEN(FirstName)-1))& Left(FirstName,1)&"ay", MID(FirstName, 3, (LEN(FirstName)-2))& Left(FirstName,2)&"ay" ) ) )

Answer (score 3):

As a curiosity I decided to see if this was possible in a formula field last night... and it turns out that it is.

The main challenge was getting it under the compiled character limit, and also under the character limit of the input box on the formula edit page (which is 3990 characters). With a bit of lateral thinking I've managed it though.

The formula is based on the simple [pig latin rules on Wikpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) and converts both the first and last name to proper case and handles the case where the `FirstName` is `null` or blank. It does not handle the case where `LastName` is `null` or blank since `LastName` is a required field on Contact.

> For words that begin with consonant sounds, the initial consonant or consonant cluster is moved to the end of the word, and "ay" (some people just add "a") is added, as in the following examples:
>
> - "happy" → "appyhay"
> - "duck" → "uckday"
> - "glove" → "oveglay"
>
> For words that begin with vowel sounds or silent letter, you just add "way" (or "wa") to the end. Examples are:
>
> - "egg" → "eggway"
> - "inbox" → "inboxway"
> - "eight" → "eightway"

The main part of the formula is as follows:

```
CASE(
  FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
    0, LastName + "way",
    1, LastName + "way",
    RIGHT
    (
      LastName, 
      LEN(LastName) - FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) + 1
    )
    +
    LEFT
    (
      LastName, 
      FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) - 1
    )
    +
    "ay"
)
```

This finds the first vowel in the name by substituting all vowels with `#`.

Then if the word doesn't have any vowels, or the vowel is the first letter then it simply appends `way` to the end of the word.

If the vowel is anywhere else in the word then it splits the word based on the position of the first vowel, moves all of the consonants to the end and appends `ay` to the end of the word.

---

Ok, and now for the full thing, which handles proper casing the name (hence all the repetition) and does both the `FirstName` and `LastName` fields. Enjoy.

One thing I would note is that using a single formula field is definitely not the best way to do this, but it was an interesting challenge to see if it was possible.

```
IF(
  NOT(ISBLANK(FirstName)),
  UPPER(
    LEFT(
      CASE(
        FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
          0, FirstName + "way",
          1, FirstName + "way",
          RIGHT
          (
            FirstName, 
            LEN(FirstName) - FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) + 1
          )
          +
          LEFT
          (
            FirstName, 
            FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) - 1
          )
          +
          "ay"
      ), 
      1
    )
  )
  +
  LOWER(
    RIGHT(
      CASE(
        FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
          0, FirstName + "way",
          1, FirstName + "way",
          RIGHT
          (
            FirstName, 
            LEN(FirstName) - FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) + 1
          )
          +
          LEFT
          (
            FirstName, 
            FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) - 1
          )
          +
          "ay"
      ), 
      LEN(FirstName) 
      +
      CASE(
        FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(FirstName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
          0, 2,
          1, 2,
          1
      )
    )
  )
  +
  " ",
  ""
)
+
UPPER(
  LEFT(
    CASE(
      FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
        0, LastName + "way",
        1, LastName + "way",
        RIGHT
        (
          LastName, 
          LEN(LastName) - FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) + 1
        )
        +
        LEFT
        (
          LastName, 
          FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) - 1
        )
        +
        "ay"
    )
    , 1
  )
)
+
LOWER(
  RIGHT(
    CASE(
      FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
        0, LastName + "way",
        1, LastName + "way",
        RIGHT
        (
          LastName, 
          LEN(LastName) - FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) + 1
        )
        +
        LEFT
        (
          LastName, 
          FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")) - 1
        )
        +
        "ay"
    ), 
    LEN(LastName) 
    +
    CASE(
      FIND("#", SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(LastName), "A", "#"), "E", "#"), "I", "#"), "O", "#"), "U", "#")),
        0, 2,
        1, 2,
        1
    )
  )
)
```